# How to avoid null checking wrapped objects for each of the methods implemented on a Wrapper Class

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, optimization, refactoring

So I have 2 classes for the moment(there might be more in the future) that are similar they both represent data from a Track

```
private Track track;
private TrackSearchResult trackSearchResult;
```

These classes are auto-generated from Json Schema. They have no relation , but they contain similar methods.

So I have created a wrapper class to encapsulate both of them so I just have 1 class that I use for everything (Like playing a track).

```
public class ExoPlayerTrack implements IPlayerTrack {


private Track track;
private TrackSearchResult trackSearchResult;


public ExoPlayerTrack(Track track) {
    this.track = track;
}

public ExoPlayerTrack(TrackSearchResult trackSearchResult) {
    this.trackSearchResult = trackSearchResult;
}



@Override
public String getTrackName() {
    if (track != null) {
        return track.getName();
    } else if (trackSearchResult != null) {
        return trackSearchResult.getTrackName();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have defined an interface IPlayerTrack that has the common methods between the 2 similar Track Classes.

```
public interface IPlayerTrack {
    public String getTrackName();
    public String getReleaseName();
    public String getArtistName();
    public String getTrackId();
    public String getReleaseId();
    public String getArtistId();
    public String getImageUrl();
    public long getDuration();
    }
```

So I need to implement every method of the interface by checking first for null to see which from the two Track classes was used to initialise the Wrapper Class which is very nasty.
Is there any way this can be avoided without touching the auto-generated model classes??? Maybe using Java 8 or Guava or a design pattern?

```
@Override
    public String getReleaseName() {
        if (track != null) {   //AVOID
            return track.getReleaseName();
        } else if (trackSearchResult != null) {
            return trackSearchResult.getReleaseName();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

 @Override
public String getTrackName() {
    if (track != null) {
        return track.getName();
    } else if (trackSearchResult != null) {
        return trackSearchResult.getTrackName();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that also the method names are slightly different in some cases (getName/getTrackName).

Comment: Why not check at the place where you are getting Track object if it's null or not`? And it's a good practice to check if object is null, why do you want to avoid it?

Answer (score 4):

You should simply define *two* different wrapper classes, both implementing the same interface: one wrapping Track, and the other wrapping TrackSearchResult.

No null check necessary anymore, except in the constructor (which should throw a NullPointerException if the given Track or TrackSearchResult is null).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `Optional`?

```
interface Track {

    public void play();
};

public void test() {
    Track a = null;
    Track b = new Track() {

        @Override
        public void play() {
            System.out.println("Play");
        }

    };
    Optional.<Track>ofNullable(a).orElse(b).play();
}
```

It is more a syntactic sugar coating than @JBNizet's suggestion but it is an alternative.